# Slideshow Fullscreen Background

Tags: html, css

I have managed to get a fully functional background slideshow onto my page, but when the page is viewed on smaller screens the slideshow is shifted to the right. This is built with only HTML and CSS. The slideshow is responsive by default and does resize the image as screen size shrinks, but adds an odd margin or padding when the window is scaled to a smaller size.
Any help would be appreciated.

HTML

```
<div class="crossfade">
  <figure></figure>
  <figure></figure>
  <figure></figure>
  <figure></figure>
  <figure></figure>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.crossfade > figure {
  animation: imageAnimation 30s linear infinite 0s;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: center center;
  color: transparent;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.crossfade{padding:0px;}
/*add images to slideshow*/
.crossfade > figure:nth-child(1) { background-image: url('Images/Logo_PNG.png'); }
.crossfade > figure:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 6s;
  background-image: url('Images/Breakfast_Icon.png');
}
.crossfade > figure:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 12s;
  background-image: url('Images/Mountain_wolf.png');
}
.crossfade > figure:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 18s;
  background-image: url('Images/Ice_Cream_Logo.png');
}
.crossfade > figure:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 24s;
  background-image: url('Images/Night_Sky_Scene.png');
}
/*crossfade between imgs*/
@keyframes 
imageAnimation {  0% {
 animation-timing-function: ease-in;
 opacity: 0;
}
 8% {
 animation-timing-function: ease-out;
 opacity: 1;
}
 17% {
 opacity: 1
}
 25% {
 opacity: 0
}
 100% {
 opacity: 0
}
}
```

Comment: This sounds as if the problem is not the code you have posted. I assume this is not the complete code but only a code snippet!? Am I right that you are using some framework (e.g. bootstrap)?

Comment: You are correct as this is the snippet of code that runs the slideshow. Also, I am not using any type of framework like bootstrap. The site that the slideshow is running on is HTML and CSS

Comment: I can't see a problem with your code here. Guess you have to use the dev tools in your browser to figure out where the margin/padding comes from and why it is triggered.

Comment: Will do, thanks for giving it a look though. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this may be caused by the default CSS values on the figure element. If you look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp), you can see that figure HTML element has these default values:

```
display: block;
margin-top: 1em;
margin-bottom: 1em;
margin-left: 40px;
margin-right: 40px;
```

I believe the 40px margin left & right are causing this additional spacing your seeing. Try adding `margin: 0px;` to your `.crossfade > figure` CSS selector like this:

```
.crossfade > figure {
  animation: imageAnimation 30s linear infinite 0s;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: center center;
  color: transparent;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  margin: 0; /* <- SET MARGIN TO ZERO HERE */
}
```

Comment: This sounds very plausible.